# Можно ли сделать yield вложенным во второй вызов?

Tags: python

Можно ли в python использовать yield вложенным во второй уровень вызова?

Вот такой вариант выдает ошибку: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

```
def f1():
    for i in range(0, 5):
        yield i

def f2():
    f1()

for i in f2():
    print(i)
```

Хочется, что бы не делать перевызовы, типа такого:

```
def f1():
    for i in range(0, 5):
        yield i

def f2():
    for i in f1():
        yield i

for i in f2():
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить использовать `yield from`

```
def f1():
    for i in range(0, 5):
        yield i

def f2():
    yield from f1()

for i in f2():
    print(i)
```